# is a vty password requierd if i have login local set with a username and a password

Tags: cisco, switch, ssh

i am trying to configure the switch to have both telnet and ssh. 
 from what i understand the "login local" command will tell the switch to ask for the user name and password i've configured using

username {name} secret {password}

from what i've learned about vty if no password is configured in (config-line)#
mode (in vty) 
i will get an error

so my questions are:

- will i get an error if i am using  "login local" + username & secret  **without a configured vty password**?
- assuming i've set vty to "login local", i've given it a vty line password and
  i gave the switch a username & secret with " *username {name} secret {password}*  " when i **telnet** will it ask me for the vty line password or the username & secret?

so basiclly the subject is "does the login local command in the vty lines set all (in telnet and ssh) login requirments to be the username & secret and if so do i need to  give the vty line a password in order for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
line vty 0 4
  login
  password vtypw
```

The `login` command tells the Router to authenticate all incoming virtual terminal sessions (telnet, ssh, etc) via the password set *within* `line vty 0 4`. In the case above, it means use `vtypw`.

```
username teddy password teddybear

line vty 0 4
  login local
```

The `login local` command tells the Router to authenticate all incoming virtual terminal sessions via the local username database -- aka, users created using the `username XXX password YYY` command.

Using `login local` skips the checking and validating against the VTY password set within `line vty 0 4`.  Therefore, **you do *not* need a `password` within `line vty 0 4` if you have `login local` set**.

---

> will i get an error if i am using "login local" + username & secret without a configured vty password?

No, no errors. I just tested it in GNS3.

> assuming i've set vty to "login local", i've given it a vty line password and i gave the switch a username & secret with " username {name} secret {password} " when i telnet will it ask me for the vty line password or the username & secret?

It will ask you for a username and expect the one from the local username database. Using the vty line password will not allow you access to the device.

Answer (score 2):

Eddie's answer is 100% correct. I just want to add that you can also use [this technique:](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/security/configuration/guide/fsecur_c/scfathen.html#wp1001032)

```
Router(config)# username teddy password teddybear    
Router(config)# aaa new-model
Router(config)# aaa authentication login default local
```

Comment: can you explain more about what exacty "aaa" means?

Answer (score 0):

1. No. You can set only username without password. This means the password is empty string / characters. If login local is used, it will require a password during login. Just 'Press Enter' only and you will be granted access.

> Router(config)#username Jon

2. Regardless if 'vty access' set to SSH or/and Telnet, so long 'login local' is applied, it will ask for username and password.